# Why isn't Xcode Cloning making any progress?

Tags: xcode, github

[image]

It was stuck at this moment.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I've tried
forced quit,
shut down the system,
deleted the Xcode and downloaded it again.

Comment: Try cloning it from command line or maybe the clone is actually finished but just that Xcode is not properly responding

Comment: You might have checked out an empty URL... usually it says "Checking out: https://github.com/repo...". Or maybe it's there but you covered it up.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to make space on your disk? It may be by that. Although it should shows a message of why. Also, contact the support team of iOS if it is not your space on disk.